# Which Stack Exchange site is best for Microsoft Excel questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am aware of [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on) but it does not, specifically, handle my question, as Excel could be on topic for multiple sites depending upon the specifics of the question. The duplicate offers a very broad overview of a variety of sites, but does not consider Super User as the answer below mentions, which makes this not a duplicate.

---

Which Stack Exchange is the best site to ask questions about Microsoft Excel (as well as potentially other Microsoft Office and [VBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications) questions)?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

[Super User](http://superuser.com) is the most appropriate (see [help](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)) for Excel questions, both on using the app but also on installing. That applies to the other MS Office applications too. Super User has a [Microsoft Excel tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel) that has a lot of activity.

In addition, specifically for VBA questions, you could also consider [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) (see [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)), although those are also acceptable on Super User too, as the Microsoft Excel tag wiki on Super User mentions you can use it along with their [VBA tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vba) for questions about Excel using VBA.

Comment: I'd just add that Excel *specific* VBA questions are also accepted on Super User.

Comment: Doesn't MS Office seem like a natural fit for its own site?  Large user base around related products...

Comment: I disagree; Most of my questions about excel comes down to how to write formulas for scenarios that are hard to search for on google. If i had a place like stack overflow for excel nerds, it would be a godsend.

Comment: Server Fault is appropriate for large estates of thousands of Excel instances