# Does a question about a program belong at Stack Overflow or Super User?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Stack Exchange site is best for Microsoft Excel questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90919/which-stack-exchange-site-is-best-for-microsoft-excel-questions)

[Do something with sequence of cells in an Excel cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005800/a-sequence-of-cells-in-excel)

Because I actually want to do something neat in the program, and the language of Excel (not sure what it's called) isn't actually being piped or ported to any other program, does it belong on Stack Overflow, or should I move it to Super User?