# If I had a question with Excel, which site would I use?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I wanted to understand how to use Excel better, and I had some question regarding it. Which exchange site is good for this?

Comment: Wrong question is specified as origin, should be https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90919/which-stack-exchange-site-is-best-for-microsoft-excel-questions?rq=1

Answer (score 58, accepted):

[Super User](https://superuser.com/) is the appropriate site for general [Microsoft Excel](https://superuser.com/tags/microsoft-excel) questions, including those dealing with built in Excel features, functions, and formulae.

And as suggested by psubsee2003 in this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155494/182513):

> For help with automation in Excel using [VBA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737%28v=office.14%29.aspx), including User-Defined Functions, then [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is probably a better resource

Answer (score 13):

I see you already accepted an answer, but just to add to the existing answer, I think the best Stack Exchange site depends on your exact usage.

For general Excel questions, including those dealing with built in Excel features, functions, and formulas, [Super User](https://superuser.com/) is absolutely the correct site.

But for help with automation with Excel using [VBA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737%28v=office.14%29.aspx), including UDF (User Defined Functions), then [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is probably a better resource