# What's the normal delay for a flag to be dismissed?

Tags: support, flags

Looking at my flagging history, I see quite a few (got 8 now) active ones dated as far back as August 9.

Sometimes a flag gets addressed almost instantaneously, other times it just sits & wait there.

Is it because I tend to flag edge cases /debatable stuff (like [excel-formula](/questions/tagged/excel-formula) questions [that would belong on SuperUser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194726/why-is-there-an-excel-formulas-tag/194731#194731), or questions posting working code and asking for a code review, which is suitable for CodeReview.SE)? Or am I "flagged" as a trigger-happy flagger and my flags are just being ignored unless they're obviously warranted?

I'm sure it's only because there's too many flags and not enough flag reviewers (is that 10K+ users or just diamonds/mods?), but what would be a "normal" delay for a flag to be reviewed?

--

As I was tagging this question, the [flag-weight](/questions/tagged/flag-weight) tag came up as a suggestion; this makes me wonder, have I shot myself in the foot? Where can I see my "flag weight" and what's an ok value? Lastly, what can I do to "flag better"?

Comment: Don't worry about flag-weight. You can't see it. I also read a while back that moderators were back logged on custom flags.

Comment: @FDinoff: Yes, we are :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flag weight is gone dead and buried<sup>1</sup>.  It used to be displayed to the users, then it was a hidden stat that was used to help rank your flags amongst your peers, now it is effectively ignored.

Depends on the type of flag, they can go into different queues, so that can dictate how quickly they are handled.

- Flagging as "Does not belong here or is a duplicate" goes into the 3K close queue for regular used to handle.
- Not An Answer and Very Low Quality flags go into Low Quality post queue, but also go into the Moderator review queue.
- Spam/Offensive flags go to the diamond moderator queue but can be handled automatically if enough users flag it.
- Custom flags (other) still go to the diamond moderator queue

Flags that go into the Review queues are automatically handled when enough users review the post and the status is based on the number of users who agree and disagree with your flag.  Until that happens, they qill still be listed as "Active".

I actually have a "Does not belong here or is a duplicate" flag still open from June 2013, so one from early August is nothing.  It will be handled when users review the flag.  Or if the question remains open, the flag will be left in limbo (a side effect of the new method for handling flags)

<sup>1 - There are numerous comments from the community team and developers spread around various posts suggesting it is no longer used, although the database field is still present (for now).  [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/182513) is the closest I can find to official announcement of the discussion to remove it but it predates the change, but here's a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188379/please-revisit-the-decision-not-to-let-people-remove-moderator-flags#comment580092_188379) from Nick saying he could drop the field from the DB</sup>

Comment: Shouldn't the [flag-weight] meta-tag be vaporized then?

Comment: @retailcoder I would say no mostly because old questions about flag weight should still have it.

Comment: ...Or at least stop it from being suggested!

Comment: @retailcoder why does it matter if the tag is suggested?  You should read the wiki, or at least the excerpt before using it?  You shouldn't be using a tag if you don't know if it is applicable or not.  If it is applicable, someone can always add it later.

Comment: @retailcoder although in fairness, the tag doesn't say that flag weight is gone, but the point is still, you should apply tags that you know are applicable, regardless of what is suggested, at least in my opinion.

Comment: Yup. That's why I put it there - because I hovered and read the description and though "hmm this might have a role here"... although I wouldn't have selected it if it said something like "Note: flag weight is no longer in use since mid-June 2013"...

Comment: @psubsee2003 I might be wrong, but think not an answer flags only go into the moderator queue. The flag dialog lists not an answer under flag for diamond mod attention.

Comment: Where do you get the information that flag weight is now "effectively ignored"? I thought it still ordered the flags in the moderator queue. When was that changed?

Comment: @CodyGray I saw a comment from Anna a few months back - let me see if I can find it

Comment: @JoshuaDwire I thought I've seen disputed flags for "not an answer" before suggesting they do go to the 10K queue - let me see if I can find one.

Comment: @CodyGray couldn't find that one, but found one from Nick, it's been added to the answer

Comment: So what does ["looks at helpful/declined up to a cap"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188379/please-revisit-the-decision-not-to-let-people-remove-moderator-flags#comment580121_188379) mean? It's not flag weight in the traditional sense, but there's some kind of weighting going on there.