# Where should I ask about LibreOffice on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

My favorite office suite is [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/).

What sites on the Stack Exchange network are the most appropriate to ask usage questions about it?

For example: How can I set a visual queue for empty lines in LibreOffice Writer? Or, where do I configure measures from inches to centimeters in LibreOffice Calc?

Comment: There are several sites that have questions about LibreOffice, I'm looking for some context on where and why the questions are most appropriate. I was also surprised not to find a previous thread listing the possibilities.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the answer would be similar to where to ask questions about using MS Office products, like this one: [If I had a question with Excel, which site would I use?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155487/756727)

It depends on what *exactly* about LibreOffice do you want to ask.

Is it about general usage (installation, running the software, [using its command line parameters](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/guide/start_parameters.html?DbPAR=SHARED#bm_id3156410), configuring settings, how-to, etc.)?

- Consider [Super User with its libreoffice tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/libreoffice)

Is it about general usage on a particular flavor or distribution of Linux?

- If it's on Ubuntu, it seems to be accepted as well at [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/libreoffice) (this matches their [on-topic list](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) that includes "*Running third-party applications on Ubuntu*")
- If it's not Ubuntu, it seems to be accepted at [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/libreoffice) (this matches their [on-topic list](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that includes "*Applications packaged in *nix distributions (note: being [cross-platform does not disqualify](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/97/29))*"

Is it about automating something with macros or writing code that uses the [LibreOffice API](https://api.libreoffice.org/)?

- Consider Stack Overflow (see this [sample question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62509424/2745495))

Is it about writing formulas?

- There is quite a bit of discussion related to [whether Excel formulas are on-topic for SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261875/2745495) or whether writing spreadsheet formulas are considered as programming. But it seems this is a point of overlap and formula-type questions seem to be accepted on either SO or SU. The same guidelines should also then apply to LibreOffice formulas.
- On SO, the [excel tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/excel/info) has this note which can help in deciding on which platform to post on: "*Only for questions on programming against Excel objects or files, or complex formula development...General help regarding MS Excel for single worksheet functions is available at Super User*"

Is it about asking which plugin or extension is best for something?

- Consider [Software Recommendations with its libreoffice tag](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/libreoffice).

Comment: I'm think this answer is very good and I consider accepting it. But I also noticed the tag with most posts on the subject is on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tags/libreoffice/topusers). Since there are so many sites on the network I will leave the question open for some more time and wait to see if more answers come in. Perhaps there are other places where questions about LibreOffice are also asked that I'm not aware of.

Comment: @bad_coder Ahh I forgot about AskUbuntu and Unix&Linux. If the question is about issues installing and running the software on a particular platform, then asking it on a platform-specific community makes sense. Edited it in. Though, I think knowing whether it's a distro-specific issue might be difficult for askers, so going with Super User might still be a good default.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [Super User](https://superuser.com) might be the answer.